# typescript angular2.d.ts error "Expecting new line or semicolon"

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript1.5

my latest `WebStorm10.0.2` raise Error about `"angular2.d.ts"` that "Expecting new line or semicolon." in line 15-19 and line 32-37.

Angular2 team make a mistake at the 5min start example? I can't believe, it must be my mistake.

So:

I clone step by step follow the "5min quick start of angular2"(https://angular.io/).

I have already move 'index.html' and 'app.ts' from 'complete' to the Base-Path.

I have also change my `WebStorm10.0.2` Compiler version to custom directory which contains typescriptService.js.

Still not work...

My typescript version is 1.5Beta.

```
interface List<T> extends Array<T> {
}
interface Type {}

declare module "angular2/angular2" {
  function bootstrap(appComponentType: any): void;
  function Component({
    selector,
    properties,
    hostListeners,
    injectables,
    lifecycle,
    changeDetection
    }:{
      selector:string,
      properties?:Object,
      hostListeners?:Object,
      injectables?:List<any>,
      lifecycle?:List<any>,
      changeDetection?:string
    });

  function View({
      templateUrl,
      template,
      directives,
      formatters,
      source,
      locale,
      device
    }: {
      templateUrl?: string,
      template?: string,
      directives?: List<Type>,
      formatters?: List<Type>,
      source?: List<any>,
      locale?: string,
      device?: string
    });
  function For();
  function If();
}
```

Comment: It seems to be compiling perfectly well here. Are you sure the error is in this file? Does it have the correct line endings (e.g. Unix or Windows)?

Comment: Just began having this issue with Typescript 2.1.4 and the latest Webstorm.  I think everything still runs fine, but I get all OCD about squiggly red lines...

Answer (score 0):

Check your `tsc` version through `tsc -v` on the command line and see if the result is `1.5.0-beta`. Chances are that you are using an earlier version because you have more than one installed in your system (one through npm, other probably when you installed a version of Visual Studio).

To check the installed versions of `tsc` (if you are on a windows environment) use the command line and type `where tsc`, the results will be a list of directories if you have more directories than the npm ones just go to your Path system variable and remove them.

Be sure to open a new command line in order to test `tsc` again, because the old path variables don't refresh for the already open command lines.

Comment: These is very interesting help.  However, I'm not sure it solves the question.  Shouldn't this rather be a comment ?

Comment: well i tried just now  to change it to the comment section but it seems i need 50 reputation to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WebStorm 10.0.4, which is configured with TypeScript 1.4 by default. It was giving me "missing semicolons" type errors until I've reconfigured WebStorm to use TypeScript 1.5 beta.  It's in Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> TypeScript -> Compiler version.